# NAudio Get Audio Samples

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

I am using NAudio to get the sample from the song that is currently playing and draw the waveform as the song plays. I am using `AudioFileReader` and `ToSampleProvider` to get all samples as `float` and then I plot them into an `InkCanvas` while the song is playing. My problem is that the samples don't seem to match the sound. I also have verify this by using this same song in the WPF example that is located in the source code of NAudio. In the example the waveform matches the sound, but in my application it doesn't. So I was wondering if someone could help me find out what I am doing (or reading) wrong or if maybe my drawing logic is wrong.

Here is my current code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ISampleProvider provider;
    private DispatcherTimer timer;
    private AudioFileReader reader;

    private WaveOut waveOut;
    private StylusPointCollection topPoints, bottomPoints;
    private DrawingAttributes attr;

    private double canvasHeight, canvasWidth;
    private int samplesGroupSize;
    private double drawPos = 0;

    private StrokeCollection _WaveformLines;
    public StrokeCollection WaveformLines
    {
        get { return _WaveformLines; } 
        set
        {
            _WaveformLines = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("WaveformLines");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        reader = new AudioFileReader("C:\\Users\\Agustin\\Desktop\\DragonRider.mp3");
        waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.Init(reader);

        provider = reader.ToSampleProvider(); //Here I get the samples
        reader.Position = 0; //Go to the position 0 after reading the samples

        canvasHeight = Waveform.ActualHeight;
        canvasWidth = Waveform.ActualWidth;

        WaveformLines = new StrokeCollection();
        topPoints = new StylusPointCollection();
        topPoints.Add(new StylusPoint(0, (canvasHeight / 2)));
        topPoints.Changed += topPoints_Changed;
        bottomPoints = new StylusPointCollection();
        bottomPoints.Add(new StylusPoint(0, (canvasHeight / 2)));
        bottomPoints.Changed += topPoints_Changed;
        WaveformLines.Add(new Stroke(topPoints));
        WaveformLines.Add(new Stroke(bottomPoints));

        attr = new DrawingAttributes();
        attr.Color = Colors.Green;
        attr.Width = 1.5;
        attr.Height = 1;

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
        samplesGroupSize = (int)(timer.Interval.TotalSeconds * reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate); //The value for this is 44.
    }

    private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        waveOut.Play();
    }
    private void PauseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        waveOut.Pause();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
        {
            TimeLabel.Content = string.Format("Time: {0}", reader.CurrentTime.ToString(@"mm\:ss\:ff")); //NEED TO KEEP WORKING
            float[] samps = new float[samplesGroupSize];
            provider.Read(samps, 0, samps.Length);
            float max = Max(samps);
            float min = Min(samps);
            topPoints.Add(new StylusPoint(drawPos, (canvasHeight / 2) - ((canvasHeight / 2) * max)));
            bottomPoints.Add(new StylusPoint(drawPos, (canvasHeight / 2) - ((canvasHeight / 2) * min)));
            drawPos += 2;
            if (drawPos > canvasWidth)
            {
                WaveformLines.Clear();
                topPoints = new StylusPointCollection();
                topPoints.Add(new StylusPoint(0, (canvasHeight / 2)));
                bottomPoints = new StylusPointCollection();
                bottomPoints.Add(new StylusPoint(0, (canvasHeight / 2)));
                WaveformLines.Add(new Stroke(topPoints));
                WaveformLines.Add(new Stroke(bottomPoints));
                drawPos = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private float Min(float[] samps)
    {
        float max = samps[0];
        foreach (float s in samps)
        {
            if (s > max)
                max = s;
        }
        return max;
    }
    private float Max(float[] samps)
    {
        float min = samps[0];
        foreach (float s in samps)
        {
            if (s < min)
                min = s;
        }
        return min;
    }

    //I excluded the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation, but in the
    //actual code is located here
}
```

I know this drawing algorithm is not very good but I have tried others and they also seem to not follow the audio.

Thanks.

NOTE: I know that there are similar question, but the other questions suggest to use things like `AudioFileReader` or `ToSampleProvider` which I am already using. My error is probably more into how I am reading the samples, maybe I am missing some bytes or have to skip some byte, or maybe some missing property that I am not setting.

Comment: You should seriously consider using the code from the [WFP example](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudioWpfDemo/AudioPlaybackDemo) which handles read/play **and the min / max calculation work**.  It will take you a little bit of effort but I promise it will be worth it.  You then will be working with a dataset that you know is in the correct form and you can focus on the drawing part.  Look closely at `AudioPlayback.cs` and its relationship to `SampleAggregator.cs`

Comment: I appreciate the tip, and If that seems to be my only choice I will probably end up using some of the source code, but I am trying understand a little bit more about audio programming so I am actually trying to not use the source code and do it myself (actually by looking at the source code I kind broke my programmer ego, but I can live with that this time).

Comment: I should also mention that if you use that example correctly you will not have to mess around with trying to use a `DispatchTimer` to drive your updates of the waveform drawing.  I think you will find it much easier to do this when you automatically receive callbacks from `SampleAggregator` to your event delegate method `OnMaximumCalculated`, once every 100msecs (you can set a property to change this interval if you need to).

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I will check into more detail in the SampleAggregator to see how it works.

Comment: I dropped your non-visual conversion code into a test stub and the `float`s look good.

Comment: Thank you. That means then that my algorithm is wrong or maybe delay because I am using the `DispatcherTimer`. Thanks.

Comment: I have to ask --- why `StrokeCollection`?  I don't have much WPF experience but that seems better suited to other use cases.  Here are a couple of example plotting [SIN() in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104820/Drawing-Trig-Functions-via-WPF) and [Example 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/169781/Draw-wavy-line-sinewave-on-inkcanvas)

Comment: Right now I am just testing. Once I make this work, I will star looking into better ways of drawing, even adding more colors gradient or something like that.

Comment: By the way you actually helped me to detect the problem, by letting me know that the samples are correct, and as last resources you did give me a good idea of where to look more in depth within the WPF Example, so I am marking this as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow #SOReadyToHelp

Comment: Please you post the first comment as answer so that I can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should seriously consider using the portions of the code from the [WFP example](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/tree/master/NAudioWpfDemo/AudioPlaybackDemo) that handles read/play and the **min / max calculation work**.

It will take you a little bit of effort but I promise it will be worth it.

You then will be working with a dataset that you know is in the correct form and you can focus on the drawing part.  Look closely at `AudioPlayback.cs` and its relationship to `SampleAggregator.cs`.

You'll also find that getting automatic callbacks while the samples are being read (and played) is a much better way to refresh your waveform drawing than trying to use a `DispatchTimer`. It will also get you out of re-reading the wave buffer as well -- you really want to avoid that if you can.

EDIT:

I tested your conversion code and the resulting `float` values appear to be correct (in the range of -1 through 1).  So I think the problem is with the way you are plotting the waveform in WPF.